# ssrs date column in Text format but when I export into excel it should sort by date

Tags: reporting-services

There is a Date field which is in text format and in Ssrs it is formatted in Date format and when try to export Ssrs report into Excel that date column should be able to sort as per date.How to create an expression for this

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two actions if you want to have it as date format in Excel.

- First: Right click, go to textbox properties > Number and format it as date.
- Second: In the textbox use the following expression:

  ```
   =CDate(Fields!YourDateField.Value)
  ```

Now if you sort after this date field and export it to Excel it will be displayed as date format.

Comment: Yes I tried this but it’s not working becz date field data type is text so when I use above expression day is acting as month and month is acting as day. So throwing error after month 12.

Comment: So your date looks like this `02/01/2019`? Is this saved as text or as date in your dataset?

Comment: Yes u are correct 02/01/2018 as text but when I export this text into excel it should allow user to sort as date

Comment: Then you have to convert it to date with the following expression: `=DateSerial(Split("02/01/2019", "/")(2), Split("02/01/2019", "/")(0), Split("02/01/2019", "/")(1))`